# Running parallel job in a linux cluster - mpich error

Tags: cluster-computing, ubuntu-12.04, mpich

First of all I would like to say I'm not sure this the right place to ask this question, I guess it us but... If it fits better in another stackexchange site please let me know.

It's three months ago I'm in charge of a cluster with six computers (Suse Linux 9.2) running a meteorological model in forecast mode. Recently because of a cut in the power supply one of the nodes crashed. After installing Lubuntu 12.04 (Suse 9.2 disks were not available, only 10.2) I tried to reconnect this computer to the cluster:

- Installed openssh server
- Run ssh-keygen to ssh without requiring password
- Installed NFS support
- Edited /etc/fstab
- Edited /etc/hosts

Then I tried to run the met model but got this error message:

```
rm_1993: p4_error: Could not gethostbyname for host thalassa; may be invalid name : 61
p0_12316: p4_error: Child process exited while making connection to remote process on thalassa3: 0
```

After Google searching I found some issues about /etc/resolv.conf and then edited this file:

> domain ceam.es dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 nameserver 127.0.0.1

But the error message still appears. I assume I'm missing something, I am not an expert sysadmin but I have to deal with.

You can find [error log](http://ubuntuone.com/0HlGLscuW27t2ECaWbimtM), [hosts](http://ubuntuone.com/4GxhYMLrXoocYEQb4gSXHh) and [resolv.conf](http://ubuntuone.com/3JVv7jKOMYZ1NPiThVr3JA) here.

Any help or idea will be greatly appreciated, I'll go on searching over the net for a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Those messages indicate that you are running the original MPICH software (often called MPICH1).  Though you may be able to patch it back together to get your system working, you really should not run software like this that has been unsupported for so long.

I would recommend upgrading to modern MPICH (formerly called MPICH2), v3.0.1 or later.  Installation and configuration should be fairly easy, although there is a reasonable chance that any old application code that you are running might not appreciate the additional error checking that modern MPICH contains.

http://www.mpich.org/

Comment: Hi @Dave and thanks for answering. Yes, I should upgrade, hope some day. But now this is a working environment that can not be halted for upgrading, so I need to get this other node running with "old" settings. In another cluster we use mpich2 and a newer version of the met model. As soon as I can I want to upgrade the older cluster but it won't be after some months when experimental campaign ends.